# Navbar togglebutton not working on toggleClass("active");

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

this just happens right after i took a coffee break. My toggle navbutton is not working anymore whenever i resize the screen of my browser. I think this regarding the toggleClass("active");
have a look on my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $('.navbar').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky");
    }
  });
  $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
    $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
  @media(max-width: 977px) {
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .menu-btn i.active:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  .navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: 0;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbar .menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar .menu li {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#">D.N.A <span>Builders</span></a></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

i tried different approaches of debugging but it seems the click function is working  when i put alert 1 on it. but the toggleClass is not being executed.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you, please edit it to make [mre] of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per what i see that you're using @media rule, and this CSS is inside the rule, so your css is working only inside this rule when max screen size is less than 977px, so whats wrong with it ? it's working with no errors if you face errors at large screens that means that you didn't set this condition in your css code for other screens

check this snippet in case that you need it for all screens

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $('.navbar').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass("sticky");
    }
  });
  $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('.navbar .menu').toggleClass("active");
    $('.menu-btn i').toggleClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
  .max-width {
    padding: 0 50px;
  }
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background:gray;
  }
  .menu-btn i.active:before {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar .menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: 2rem;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbar .menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar .menu li {
    display: block;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="max-width">
    <div class="logo"><a href="#">D.N.A <span>Builders</span></a></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fa fa-bars">[ X ]</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: wow man thanks for this. i read the code and copare to the one i have , it seems that i have double declare something in my css which is why is not working for me. this is the effect of excessive coffee for me. thanks alot